How can a quantum particle in an infinite potential well transition between regions separated by nodes?

I don't understand, if the PD describes the probability of finding the particle at a point, how is the probability is non-zero after a node. That means (classically speaking) the particle will have to "cross" the node to be at another peak, so it'll have to be at the node to cross it, but still the PD is zero. I am confused and new to QM.

More on nodes and probability in QM.


That means (classically speaking) [...]

But this isn't classical mechanics, it is quantum mechanics. The particle doesn't have a well-defined position, so it cannot "cross the node". Your confusion is stemming from the fact that you are imagining the particle to be a little ball which is at some position at one moment in time and another position some time later. This is not how QM works, and if you don't try to shoehorn classical intuition into quantum mechanics then your question evaporates.
